# Is printf("%d", 1.0) undefined?

Tags: c, printf, glibc, stdio, libc

According to section 4.9.6.1 of the [C89 draft](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), %d is a character that specifies the type of **conversion** to be applied.

The word **conversion** implies, in my opinion, that `printf("%d", 1.0)` is defined.

Please confirm or refute this.

Comment: Right, and '%d' specifies conversion from an int. Except you didn't pass it an int.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The conversion is the conversion of a language value to a lexical representation of that value.

Your theory is wrong; behavior is undefined. The spec says (7.19.6.1p8 and 9, using C99 TC2):

> The **int** argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd.

And

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The lexical representation of `1.0` [using `%d`] is `1`, though, isn't it?

Comment: @minitech: I don't have any idea what your statement is supposed to mean.

Comment: Johannes: I think what OP is missing is that the process of taking an `int` and displaying a decimal string representing that number is a conversion. Perhaps you could stress this more clearly than I have...

Comment: Your 2nd quotation is exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't appear in the C89 draft. Are you quoting from the final C89 specification?

Comment: To quote: "The conversion is the conversion of a language value to a lexical representation of that value." What I was asking was, the lexical representation of `1.0` as an integer is `1`, right? So how can that be wrong? Anyways, doesn't matter since the edit.

Comment: @minitech printf converts the arguments, and the result of that conversion is written to standard output. The spec says "... conversion specifications, each of which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments, converting them, if applicable, according to the corresponding conversion specifier, and then writing the result to the output stream". This "conversion" is not converting between values in the language, but from a value to a sequence of characters. Just like `boost::lexical_cast<>` in the C++ world.

Comment: @Natan for the c89 draft, you could take the statement "If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.". Or simply the absence of the description for what happens with an argument different than `int` (omission of description of behavior == undefined behavior).

Answer (score 8):

Printf is a varargs function, so no conversion is possible. The compiler just arranges to push a double onto the arguments list. Printf has no way to find out that it's a double versus an int versus an elephant. Result? Chaos.

Answer (score 2):

The word "conversion" here is referring to the conversion of an `int` (which is the only acceptable argument type here) to a string of characters that make of the decimal representation of that `int`. It has nothing to do with conversion from other types (such as `double`) to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's officially undefined or an error - but it's wrong!